# Search on the last column with \ delimiter and save the email address associated to it to a variable

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, sh, ksh

I have two files.

file1.txt contains:

```
META GAIN CORP
GG$
ABG$
PEPRA_UAT
12GHR
CC$
USDP_MAIN
XQ$
PR$
MIX_DEV
```

and file2.csv contains:

```
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\Home\RD,Mailbox.FRmeshare@usdp.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\99 FLOOR,Jay.Pau@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\44 FLOOR,Jay.Pau@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\META GAIN CORP,Mary.White@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\META GAIN CORP,Sed.Rasonn@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\META GAIN CORP,Farah.Karlus@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\META GAIN CORP,Mer.Sus@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\Shares\FR\USDP WATER\ABG$,Geboi.torm@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\Shares\FR\USDP WATER\ABG$,Geboi.torm@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\Shares\FR\USDP WATER\ABG$,Josua.Durant@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\HHR DATABASE,Geboi.torm@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\HHR DB2 EDU,Geboi.torm@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\HHR DB2 EDU,Alex.Gold@usdp.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\NICE SHORT,Leni.Braft@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\PRO DEV,Kath.wetfield@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\DUK 20154 USER,
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\DUK 20154 USER,Carlo.Gomez@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\FARE GRUST,Jason.Desanre@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\XYZ GROUP,Aaron.Lee@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\XYZ TEAM TOOLKIT,Aaron.Lee@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\BILLING ELEMENT,Matheo.Logan@usdpwater.org
\\fr.usdp.org\SOLE\SHARES\FR\USDP WATER\RRT_SEC,John.Tian@usdpwater.org
```

had this on my script but I can't exactly get the last column if there are spaces.

```
for sr in `cat file1.txt`; do
            sname=`echo ${sr} | awk -F: '{ print $1 }'`
            emdrs=`grep -Fw "${sname}" file2.csv | awk -F',' '{print$2}' | sed 's/[[:space:]]//' | xargs | sed -e 's/ /,/g'`
            echo "$sname || To: $emdrs" >> details.txt
done
```

details.txt output

```
META || Mary.White@usdpwater.org,Sed.Rasonn@usdpwater.org,Farah.Karlus@usdpwater.org,Mer.Sus@usdpwater.org
GAIN || Mary.White@usdpwater.org,Sed.Rasonn@usdpwater.org,Farah.Karlus@usdpwater.org,Mer.Sus@usdpwater.org
CORP || Mary.White@usdpwater.org,Sed.Rasonn@usdpwater.org,Farah.Karlus@usdpwater.org,Mer.Sus@usdpwater.org
```

but what i wanted is that

```
META GAIN CORP || To: Mary.White@usdpwater.org,Sed.Rasonn@usdpwater.org,Farah.Karlus@usdpwater.org,Mer.Sus@usdpwater.org
```

and I should also be able to search string with $ like this one ABG$ ) and not including the duplicate email.

```
ABG$ || To: Geboi.torm@usdpwater.org,Josua.Durant@usdpwater.org
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
while read -r sr; do
  emails="$(grep -F "\\${sr}," file2.csv | cut -d',' -f2 | sort -u | tr -d '\r' | paste -sd',')"
  if [ -n "$emails" ]; then
    echo "$sr || To: $emails"
  fi
done < file1.txt
```

Some explanations:

- `grep -F` - treat pattern (`$sr`) as fixed strings and not regular expressions to avoid `$` matching end of line
- `cut -d',' -f2` - Cut the result at the comma and only output the 2nd part
- `sort -u` - remove duplicates
- `tr -d '\r'` - remove carriage returns
- `paste -sd','` - join lines with comma
- `if [ -n "$emails" ]` only output if `$emails` is not empty

Comment: thanks @mhutter.
it's not working on the actual .csv file i'm using BUT when i copy it and create a new file (vi newfile.csv) it is working. any idea why?

Comment: I'm gonna take a wild guess and assume the original file contains window line endings (CRLF instead of just LF). I amended the answer to account for that.

Comment: Thank you @mhutter. Works like a charm. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

One `awk` idea (replaces OP's current `for` loop):

```
awk -F',|\\\' '                                         # field delimiter of "," or "\"
FNR==NR { srlist[$1]
          next
        }
        { email=$NF
          if (email == "") next
          sr=$(NF-1)

          if (sr in srlist && emlist[sr] !~ email) {    # skip duplicate email addresses
                delim=(emlist[sr]) ? "," : ""
                emlist[sr]=emlist[sr] delim email
             }
        }
END     { for (sr in emlist)
              print sr " || To: " emlist[sr]
        }
' file1.txt file2.csv
```

This generates:

```
ABG$ || To: Geboi.torm@usdpwater.org,Josua.Durant@usdpwater.org
META GAIN CORP || To: Mary.White@usdpwater.org,Sed.Rasonn@usdpwater.org,Farah.Karlus@usdpwater.org,Mer.Sus@usdpwater.org
```

**NOTES:**

- while a bit more typing than OP's current `for` loop, this approach requires a single scan of `file2.awk` and eliminates the 7 subprocess calls (for each pass through OP's `for` loop)
- for any appreciable volume of data an `awk` solution should be noticeably faster
- for the sample data provided:

  - 0.65 secs: `awk`
  - 1.80 secs: `bash/for-loop`

Comment: `emlist[sr] !~ email` would fail for various email addresses due to partial matches and regexp metachars like `.` matching. Instead of a regexp comparison with no anchors you need a string comparison with anchors (or a regexp one with anchors if you escape all possible regexp metachars).

Answer (score 0):

A shell loop is never the right approach for manipulating text, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Using GNU awk for arrays of arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[\\\\,]" }
NR == FNR {
    tgts[$0]
    next
}
{
    sr = $(NF-1)
    email = $NF
}
(sr in tgts) && (email != "") {
    emails[sr][email]
}
END {
    for ( sr in emails ) {
        printf "%s || To:", sr
        sep = " "
        for ( email in emails[sr] ) {
            printf "%s%s", sep, email
            sep = ","
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1.txt file2.csv
ABG$ || To: Geboi.torm@usdpwater.org,Josua.Durant@usdpwater.org
META GAIN CORP || To: Mary.White@usdpwater.org,Farah.Karlus@usdpwater.org,Mer.Sus@usdpwater.org,Sed.Rasonn@usdpwater.org
```

Comment: It's not working as well if i'm using the original file. I guess it's because the original file contains window line endings (CRLF instead of just LF) like what @mhutter mentioned.

Comment: @gafm then handle them in any of the usual ways, e.g. add `{sub(/\r$/,"")}` as the first line of the awk script or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it for other suggestions.